# Aggregating using arbitrary precedence in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given the dataframe

```
  Column1 Column2  Column3
0       a     foo        1
1       a     bar        2
2       b     baz       12
3       b     foo        4
4       c     bar        6
5       c     foo        3
6       c     baz        7
7       d     foo        9
```

I'd like to groupby Column1, using an arbitrary order of precedence for which values to keep from column3.

For example, if the order of precedence is:

1. baz
2. bar
3. foo

then I would expect the output to show as

```
         Column2
Column1         
a              2
b             12
c              7
d              9
```

with the "a" group keeping the "bar" value because there is no "baz" for the "a" group, "b" group keeping the "baz" value, and so on.

What's the most elegent way to do this?  Right now I'm applying a series of apply lambda's to work through each item, but it feels sloppy.

EDIT:
What if the precendence goes across multiple columns?

Ex.

```
  Column1 Column2 Column3  Column4
0       a     foo    john        1
1       a     bar     jim        2
2       b     baz    jack       12
3       b     foo     jim        4
4       c     bar    john        6
5       c     foo    john        3
6       c     baz    jack        7
7       d     foo    jack        9
```

If the order of precedence across both Column2 and Column3 is:

1. jim
2. baz
3. foo

then I would expect the output to show as

```
        Column2  Column3
Column1                 
a           jim        2
b           jim        4
c           baz        7
d           foo        9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with the below logic with `map` then `groupby+transform`

```
order = ['baz','bar','foo']
d = {v:k for k,v in dict(enumerate(order)).items()}
out = df.assign(k=df['Column2'].map(d))

print(df[out['k'].eq(out.groupby("Column1")['k'].transform("min"))])
```

---

```
  Column1 Column2  Column3
1       a     bar        2
2       b     baz       12
6       c     baz        7
7       d     foo        9
```

EDIT , for multiple columns, using the same logic as above, here is a way:

```
order = ['jim','baz','foo']
d = {i:e for e,i in enumerate(order)}

s = df[['Column2','Column3']].replace(d).apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').min(1)

out = (s[s.eq(s.groupby(df['Column1']).transform("min"))]
       .replace(dict(enumerate(order))).rename("Col"))

df.loc[out.index,["Column1","Column4"]].join(out)

  Column1  Column4  Col
1       a        2  jim
3       b        4  jim
6       c        7  baz
7       d        9  foo
```

Comment: Thanks for this! What do you think about the added complexity of the ordered items being stored across two different columns? Maybe create and additional column with the highest precedence item in it, and then run this logic on that new column?

Comment: Hello anky, Thank you for sharing nice solution, could you please explain more on `v:k for k,v in dict(enumerate(order)).items()` please will be grateful to you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 we are creating an enumerator as a dictionary and reversing the keys and values so that we can use map to the existing series, you can also directly use something like `{i:e for e,i in enumerate(order)}`

Comment: @bcalc you can try what Allolz suggested in their answer, I have also edited another way using `replace` and a similar logic

Answer (score 3):

If you have an order for all values in 'Column2' you can use `loc` after setting the index to impose your custom order, then `drop_duplicates` to keep only the highest precedence.

```
order = ['baz', 'bar', 'foo']
df.set_index('Column2').loc[order].drop_duplicates('Column1')

        Column1  Column3
Column2                 
baz           b       12
baz           c        7
bar           a        2
foo           d        9
```

---

In your second case if you need to do this across multiple columns we first `melt` such that Column2 and Column3 are stacked into one long Series and the rest follows the same as above:

```
order = ['jim', 'baz', 'foo']
(df.melt(id_vars=['Column4', 'Column1'], value_vars=['Column2', 'Column3'])
   .drop(columns='variable')
   .set_index('value')
   .loc[order]
   .drop_duplicates('Column1')
)

       Column4 Column1
value                 
jim          2       a
jim          4       b
baz          7       c
foo          9       d
```

Comment: Thanks for this! What do you think about the added complexity of the ordered items being stored across two different columns? Maybe create and additional column with the highest precedence item in it, and then run this logic on that new column?

Comment: @bcalc In that case I'd first `melt` then you can apply any of the solutions as you would have in the first case.

Answer (score 2):

You can try converting `Column2` to categorical:

```
df['Column2'] = pd.Categorical(df['Column2'], ordered=True, categories=['baz','bar','foo'])

df.sort_values(['Column1','Column2']).drop_duplicates('Column1')
```

Output:

```
  Column1 Column2  Column3
1       a     bar        2
2       b     baz       12
6       c     baz        7
7       d     foo        9
```

Comment: Thanks for this! What do you think about the added complexity of the ordered items being stored across two different columns? Maybe create and additional column with the highest precedence item in it, and then run this logic on that new column?